# An explanation of how ShellCheck SC2048 works

Tags: shell

https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2048

```
${array[*]} will expand into multiple other arguments:
baz, foo, bar, file.txt and otherfile.jpg
```

Are `file.txt` and `otherfile.jpg` in the directory where script runs?

Here is my script

```
#!/bin/bash
array=(t1 t2)
cp ${array[*]} ./dir
```

and there are `t1 t2 t3 t4` four files in the directory where script runs. But only t1 and t2 are copied to `dir`. Why does `${array[*]}`  not expand into `t3 t4` like the shellcheck description says?

Comment: Hi, what exactly is unclear to you? `Are file.txt and otherfile.jpg in the directory where script runs?` How can we know? `But only t1 and t2 are copied to dir` and?

Comment: Hi @KamilCuk, In my script, why does `${array[*]}` not expand into `t3 t4` like the shellcheck description does?

Comment: In the _presented_ script, `${array[*]}` expands to `t1 t2`, becuase `array` contains two items `array=(t1 t2)`. I do not see a script where it would expand to `t3 t4`.

Comment: But the shellcheck description says ${array[*]} will expands to other arguments

Comment: The shellcheck description starts with `Let's say you have three arguments or array elements: baz, foo bar and *` and then continues to describe. Having `array=(baz "foo bar" "*")` then, `${array[*]}` will trigger `*` to expand to all files.

Comment: Oh, I am sorry. `*` is an element of `array`. I misunderstand it, I thought `*` is not element but only an  notation used in expression `array[*]` to refer to all elements. Now I get it, thank you very much.

Comment: The literal-asterisk case isn't the only one where the misbehavior of `${array[*]}` is observable, btw; it likewise misbehaves with spaces (or other IFS characters) as well; likewise non-asterisk globbing forms.

Answer (score 2):

> why does ${array[*]} not expand into t3 t4 like the shellcheck description says?

Because `array` does not contain literal character `*` like in the shellcheck description case.

Compare:

```
#!/bin/bash
array=(t1 t2 '*')
cp ${array[*]} ./dir
```

Tips: use `set -x` to debug scripts. Use `declare -p array` to see variable content.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you run a simple experiment which tests all four combinations of `@` and `*`, with quotes and without?

```
$ array=("a" "b" "c d" "e")
$ for x in ${array[*]} ; do echo "[$x]"; done
[a]
[b]
[c]
[d]
[e]
$ for x in ${array[@]} ; do echo "[$x]"; done
[a]
[b]
[c]
[d]
[e]
$ for x in "${array[*]}" ; do echo "[$x]"; done
[a b c d e]
$ for x in "${array[@]}" ; do echo "[$x]"; done
[a]
[b]
[c d]
[e]
```

Only the combination of double quotes with `@` causes the individual items to be expanded and then quoted to prevent them from being split, and the contents from being interpreted as globbing characters for pathname expansion.